# Cake PHP restful index method returns empty response

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I started to learn CakePhp. I am trying to make a restful application an whenever I open a browser via url http://localhost:8888/todolist/entries/index.json I get no json response.

```
   <?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
    /**
     * Entries Controller
     *
     * @property Entry $Entry
     * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
     */
    class EntriesController extends AppController {

        /**
         * @var array
         */
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    /**
     * Components
     *
     * @var array
     */
        public $components = array('Paginator', 'RequestHandler');

    /**
     * index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
        public function index() {
            $this->Entry->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('entries', $this->Paginator->paginate());

            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->layout = false;
        }
}
```

This is my routes.php:

```
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'entries', 'action' => 'index'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';

Router::mapResources('entries');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Below is a screenshot from firebug.

[image: Firebug Network screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've disabled rendering:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

hence you'll get an empty response. No need to disable rendering, use a serialized view as described in the REST and JSON/XML view docs:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Entry->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('entries', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    $this->set('_serialize', 'entries'); // that's where the magic begins
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > REST](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > JSON and XML views](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)**